# Why resizebox is not working on my informs template

Tags: tables, rotating, fit

I have to use informs class for journal Operations research and I have a very large rotated table, I used resizebox to fit it on the page, when I just used the class article, but when I used the informs class, it will not let me to use this command, and I don't know how I can fit my table anymore. Can someone help me with this?

```
          \documentclass[opre,nonblindrev]{informs3}
          \usepackage{multirow}
          %\usepackage{cleveref}
          \usepackage{algpseudocode}
          \usepackage{algorithm}
          \usepackage{graphicx}
          \usepackage{pgf}
          \usepackage{afterpage}
          \begin{document}
           \afterpage{%
           \clearpage%
           \begin{rotate}
          \begin{table}[c]
          \centering
          \TABLE
          {Summary Table of Literature Review.\label{clist}}
          %\resizebox{1.4\textwidth}{!}
          {\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}    
           first paper in addition & Yes   & No    & Yes   & No    & No    & No    & Total Completion Time \\
         \hline
         \up \down

            second paper in completion & Special & Yes   & No    & Yes   & No    & Road disaster and limitation & Minimzing the cost \\
             \end{tabular}}
              {}
          \end{table}%
          \end{rotate}%
          \clearpage%
          }

          \end{document}
```

In the website they mentioned that they used \graphicx package in the informs class, but I added it to make sure I can use the resize command. 
The informs class in available in:
 https://www.informs.org/Find-Research-Publications/INFORMS-Journals/Author-Portal/LaTeX-Style-Files

The error is : ! Argument of \Gscale@@box has an extra }.

Comment: You should use `\resizebox{1.4\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}..... body..... \end{tabular}}`

Comment: You could not use `\resizebox` at the point that you have it commented out, it would need to be before the `\begin{tabular}`

Comment: Yes, I did use \resizebox before tabular, but it didn't work, so I was just trying it on different places. But in any case, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an input error by the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I have to add an extra { before the resizebox command: so it will be like:

```
      \begin{rotate}
      \begin{table}[c]
      \centering
      \TABLE
      {Summary Table of Literature Review.\label{clist}}
      {\resizebox{1.4\textwidth}{!}
      {\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}    
       first paper in addition & Yes   & No    & Yes   & No    & No    & No    & Total Completion Time \\
     \hline
     \up \down

        second paper in completion & Special & Yes   & No    & Yes   & No    & Road disaster and limitation & Minimzing the cost \\
         \end{tabular}}}
          {}
      \end{table}%
      \end{rotate}%
```